tensorflow object detection using model_main_tf2.py
model_main_tf2.py no longer works under TF2.15 and TF 2.16. There are compatibility issues like cannot import name 'estimator' from 'tensorflow.compat.v1 . One workaround is to use TF2.13 but it would be nice if google could just update the repo to fix this here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
I have tried to downgrade to TF2.13 which is the last version I found compatible with the function for training models

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
